# Fancybox resize height iframe dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

Fancybox v1.3

Why the height of fancybox doesn't change when i change content. When i click on the button that is inside the content, there are new inputs, so the height of content was changed, but fancybox height is not equal content height. Fancybox height is equal content height at the first show.

```js
$('a[href*="invite_to_event"]').each(function () {
      $(this).fancybox({
       autoScale:false,
       type: 'iframe',
       width:585,
       scrolling:'no',
       padding:'0',
       autoSize:false,
       showCloseButton:false,
       hideOnOverlayClick:false   
});
```

Here is what i got inside iframe:

```html
<div id="invForm" class="invite_form" style="max-height:682px;">

      /*bla bla bla*/
  
 <div class="btn-group">   
  <input type="button" onclick="if ($('.group').length<10) AddOneGuestForm()" disabled="disabled" value="Добавить еще одного гостя" id="addOneBtn">
  <input name="lab1" type="text" id="lab1" class="server_element">
       <input type="submit" name="sendBtn1" value="Отправить приглашение" id="sendBtn1" class="server_element">   
  <input type="button" onclick="send_invite_click();" disabled="disabled" value="Отправить приглашение" id="sendBtn">
 </div>  
</div>
```

```css
.invite_form{
    width: 585px;
    max-height: 682px;
    min-height: 338px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't mean to change dynamically (mostly when `autoSize` is set to `false`). You may need to run the `$.fancybox.resize()` method programmatically every time you change the content length.

Comment: when i use fancybox.resize(), iframe is reloaded and all inputs are clean